# Alexa AMAZON.YesIntent/NoIntent getting into a dialog or passing to an intent for response slots

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

What's the JSON to deliver to have an ambiguous YesIntent or NoIntent go back to a dialog flow or pass it to another intent?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I don't get your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of your last intent by passing it in session attributes.

```
def yesIntent(intent,session):
last_intent = session['attributes']['current_intent']

if last_intent == "intent1":
    speech_output="this is response to intent 1"
    *Rest of the code*
elif last_intent == "intent2" :
    speech_output = "This is reponse to intent 2"
    *Rest of the code*
```

Comment: is it possible to pass it to responses from Alexa for another intent?